Snowflake Data Masking Issue. With view and table
So I have a table which have masking on its columns so I got my roles added to masking policy of that particular view.
I created a view and a table from dbt including data from that particular masked view.
Now while accessing this particular view data comes unmasked but the case is not same for table data is coming masked in it.
Can anyone suggest some way to get data unmasked in this table too.
I Have got access on all the roles through which I am accessing that views data and creating the new view and table

Hi - your question seems a bit confused as in your first sentence you mention a table but then talk about a view. Can you update it to make things clearer, please?. Can you provide the DDL for the table, view and masking policy? Is the masking policy on the table, view or both? What role have you been granted to see data unmasked?

So basically think there are 3 views A, B, C. Now on A we have masking policy on columns. NOW i needed to ingest data from A,B,C to a PowerBi dashboard so I just created a new view D and table T1 including data from A,B,C. Now I am accessing this view D and T1 using reader role and that particular reader role has access to the masking policy. I am able to see the data in view D as unmasked and in Table T data is still masked. Why is this disparity

Also I have created these 2 objects i.e. view D and Table T1 using dbt. So the role which I used in creating this tranformation role was not added to masking policy as it is a global role.

Any help would be appreciated

If you've created a Table T1 and populated it with data from View A, if the role that read the data from A and wrote it to T1 could not see the unmasked data then the masked values would have been written to the table i.e. if a masked value in View A was "ABC*****123" then that would be the actual string that would be written to the table. If the role that did the copy could see the data unmasked then all the data in the table would be unmasked for everyone - and you'd need to add a masking policy to the table if you wanted that data masked

Please share code for us to reproduce
